# how to cache firebase images

Tags: flutter, caching, firebase-storage

```
    import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class PocketBooksModel {
  String? docId;
  String? title;
  String? author;
  String? image;

  PocketBooksModel({this.docId, this.title, this.author, this.image});

  PocketBooksModel.fromMap(DocumentSnapshot data) {
    docId = data.id;
    title = data["title"];
    author = data["author"];
    image = data["image"];
  }
}
```

here is how the image is displayed in the ui code

```
NetworkImage(PocketBooks['image']),
```

I have this class witch fetch data from firestore along with images in firebase storage. I want to cache the images after they load in the app. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the cached_network_image package which you can get from pub.dev

Once you imported the package on you widget you can use a widget like this to cache the image

```
CachedNetworkImage(
        imageUrl: imageUrl ,
        imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) =>
            CircleAvatar(backgroundImage: imageProvider),
        placeholder: (context, url) => const Center(
          child: 
              CircularProgressIndicator(
                  valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(
                    primary,
                  ),
                ),
        ),
        errorWidget: (context, url, error) {
          return const Center(
            child: Icon(Icons.error, color: Colors.red),
          );
        },
      )
```

Comment: the imageUrl expects a string and im fetching my images through the class from firebase

Comment: is not this your image url string "PocketBooks['image']", becauze as you psted on your post you are using this inside a netwrokimage wich also expect a string

Comment: i got the following error:

Comment: The argument type 'CachedNetworkImage' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageProvider<Object>'.

Comment: im fetching the image inside a container decorationBox, DecorationImgae(image: NetworkImage(PocketBooks['image']),)

Comment: you can't put cached network image widget inside the decoration box of a container, maybe you can use it as a child or directly use it without the need of the container

Comment: thank you, if my ansewer helped you please accept it, by clicking oh the tick icon under the vote. thanks